# Specify aspect ratio in terms of displayed aspect ratio, not data ranges

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I specify the aspect ratio in `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` in terms of the actual displayed aspect ratio. In `imshow` the option `aspect` specifies the ratio in terms of the number of columns and rows. Consider the following code

```
z = np.random.rand(10,1000)
plt.imshow(z, aspect=1)
```

Intuitively I would expect this to create a square image (equal size of x and y). However it actually creates a super elongated image with a display aspect ratio of 100. Is there an elegant way to accomplish want I want. I know that I can extract the number of columns and rows and use those to define the aspect ratio, but this seems super hacky. Moreover, I need the displayed aspect ratio to stay the same when I modify, for example, the `xlim`

Comment: What is super hacky about using the data you have?  Does `aspect=z.shape[0]/z.shape[1]` work?

Comment: @MarkRansom you certainly mean `aspect=z.shape[1]/z.shape[0]`

Comment: sure, but then what if I change the `xlim` and `ylim` but still want to maintain the same size plots. Or something else. I'd much rather have a way to just specify the visually displayed aspect ratio that is completely agnostic to whatever the actual data ranges are

Comment: @Stef thanks for the correction, that's what I get for making a suggestion before I try it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the bounding box of the plot to be square, regardless of the size of the data on the axes, try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = np.random.rand(10, 1000)
plt.imshow(z, aspect='auto').axes.set_box_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: this works nicely, thank you. It also keeps the aspect ratio when changing the `xlim` It's similar to the answer from @Stef too

Answer (score 2):

You can set the aspect to [`´auto´`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-aspect) to always fill the plot area with data. In case of an image, you may want to additionally switch off interpolation:

```
plt.imshow(z, aspect='auto', interpolation='None')
```

Comment: thanks, but I want the ratio between the height and width of the displayed image to be a constant that I specify

Comment: just add `plt.gca().set_box_aspect(my_constant_aspect_ratio)`

Comment: ah nice that seems to be working. and it keeps the same aspect ratio after I change the `xlim` too

Answer (score 1):

For a squared figure, I would take the ratio between the number of elements in each sub-array and the number of sub-arrays.

```
plt.imshow(z, aspect=len(z[0])/len(z))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but the problem with this approach is, for example if I change the `xlim` (`plt.xlim(200,700)`) then the aspect ratio is no longer square and I have to get hacky

Comment: @Tom this answers your given question perfectly.  If your question wasn't complete, fix it!@

Comment: ok I slightly modified the question to make the request more specific.